# Given a sequence of POSIXct which include date and time how do I calculate the mean of times only (excluding days)?

Tags: r, dplyr, posixct

```
start =  as.POSIXct("2019-04-12 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")

end = as.POSIXct("2019-07-14 09:00:00", tz = "UTC")

datseq = data.frame(time_factor = seq(start,end, by = "1 hour"))

sampledat = sample(datseq$time_factor,30,replace = FALSE)
```

Given the above data, if I were to calculate the mean `mean(sampledat)` it will return the mean time of hours and days. But how can I extract only the time and calculate the mean of times only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using some help from `lubridate` library.

```
library(lubridate)

format(sampledat, '%T') %>%
  hms %>%
  period_to_seconds() %>%
  mean %>%
  as.POSIXct(origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC') %>%
  format('%T')
```

We extract the time part from `sampledat`, convert it to period object, convert that into number of seconds, take `mean` of it and display it in  "HMS" format.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Do you also need to provide it with a fixed date then?

Comment: No. If you check `sampledat` they have different dates. Dates do not matter as this extracts only the time.

Comment: I meant in the code you provide you are using origin = '1970-01-01'...

Comment: You can use any date there, it does not matter but you have to use something. Since `'1970-01-01'` is considered as unix start time I use that. Also note that everything after `mean` including `as.POSIXct` part is just to display the mean and does not impact the actual calculation.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot. I'm surprised that there isn't a simple function provided in lubridate to do this. As sometimes people aren't interest in the date of something but mean time.